# How can I test frame-rate on the PC?

Tags: framerate

For any videogame, is there some sort of program for the PC that allows you to measure frame-rate over a period of time (similar to a DigitalFoundry video)?

Comment: Do you mean measuring the framerate in a particular game/program? Or benchmarking the hardware in general?

Comment: Try asking at: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Gamers used **Fraps** tool to measure the FPS of a game.

**Fraps** is a game-video-recording application, although it also has the ability to display an FPS counter over the current game.

http://www.fraps.com/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraps

There is also a newer tool called **BandiCam** which has a very nice dark stylish and does the same.

http://www.bandicam.com/downloads/

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandicam

Comment: I'm looking for something that records, averages, and counts fps in real time, not just displays it. I can do that with Steam itself.

Answer (score 1):

I watched a few of the DigitalFoundry videos and his FPS monitor was real time, but I didn't notice anything that gave an average FPS. Are you wanting an average or real time? There are many programs that give real time FPS. One of the more popular ones seems to be Fraps. There are also graphics card monitoring tools, such as *MSI afterburner*, *EVGA Precision X*, etc. that can display a lot of on-screen data that is related to your GPU.

Comment: Is Zotac Firestorm the equivilent of MSI afterburner or EVGA Precision X?

Comment: @CamouflagedCow yeah Zotac Firestorm is also an overclocking software like Afterburner and Precision X. I've never used Firestorm, but I'd assume it also has the ability to produce on-screen display information about your GPUs performance